# ToastAndroid showWithGravity Error

Tags: react-native, toast, android-toast

Following the document, I am including a toast in my projects:

```
     import {ToastAndroid} from react-native

    ToastAndroid.showWithGravity('A toast with gravity',ToastAndroid.SHORT,ToastAndroid.TOP);
```

But I got an error:

[image]

However, if I replace it with another function, it works:

```
   ToastAndroid.show('A toast without gravity',ToastAndroid.SHORT);
```

I am using React Native 0.30.0

Is it a bug or I made the wrong way to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(...)` was implemented in ReactNative 0.31.0, upgrade your RN version.

[First implemented here: v0.31.0-stable branch.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.31-stable/Libraries/Components/ToastAndroid/ToastAndroid.android.js)